# Floating point - NaN

Tags: java, floating-point, nan, floating-point-precision

I am working on a research project on java in which some tough calculations have to be done. However I am done with most part but stuck at a point.. I have to calculate the following :

> (2.1-2.3) raised to power 0.3.

But I get the answer `NaN`.. I have tried store result with  both `float` and `double` variables, however it shows same result. Strangely when I did the same with a calculator , it showed result `-0.430512`

I can not figure out how to make it work with java
Code for same is:

```
Math.pow((provider1[k][a][m]-provider1[k][j][m]),prior[k][m]);.
```

When the values of above are `2.1`,`2.3` and `0.3` -  `NaN` is the output.

However when the values are `2.1`, `2.3` and `3`, it gets the correct value (`-0.08`). Can someone please help how to do this.

Comment: See this breakdown on fractional exponents (http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponent-fractional.html) - as the poster below states, a negative number raised to a fractional exponent is a complex number

Comment: Ya..I need to brush up my maths concepts..Moreover the Online calculator I tried also fooled me..Thanx anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be an error. Check the calculator you are using.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [`Math.pow` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29):

> - If the first argument is finite and less than zero
>
>   - if the second argument is a finite even integer, the result is equal to the result
>       of raising the absolute value of the first argument to the power of the second argument
>   - if the second argument is a finite odd integer, the result is equal to the negative of
>       the result of raising the absolute value of the first argument to the power of the
>       second argument
>   - *if the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the
>       result is NaN*.

(emphasis mine)

That is because [raising a negative number to a non-integral power yields a complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers).  One case is not being able to take the square root of a number: `(-1)^0.5`.  The result doesn't exist in real numbers, and it inspired the imaginary number `i` which in math is defined to be the square root of `-1`.  In general, raising a negative number to a non-integral power yields a complex number, which is the sum of a real number and an imaginary number.

Comment: O.K. thank you..I need to brush up my maths concepts..Moreover the online calculator (link : http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/exponent-fractions.php) also needs to do the same..:p

Comment: Yes, it looks like the calculator at the link you gave needs to be corrected.  Even Windows Calculator gives "Invalid Input".

Comment: Ya..Should have tried Windows calculator..It didn't came to my mind

Comment: check my solution, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a complex number to me.

My HP 15C scientific calculator tells me that (-0.2)^0.3 is an error.

Time for you to buy a new calculator.

Comment: I tried it online..http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/exponent-fractions.php at this link

Comment: You were right..The online calculator I tried is showing wrong results..Thanx anyways

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you or someone else in the future:

The link below uses the example below to explain the mathematics behind the complex number solutions you get when you raise a negative base to a fractional number and how abs() can help you.  When you try to do with with standard Math.* functions it doesn't know how to handle the complex portion of the solution.  Using Java as an example, to make a calculation with a negative base and a positive fractional exponent, normally one could use:

```
double d = Math.pow(base,exp);
```

However, with a negative base and fractional exponent this results in NaN because complex solutions exist.

If the complex portion of a solution doesn't matter to you (like it didn't in my case), you can use this approach.

The equation used in this example is a parameter "Phi" in the Yamada and Gunn modification to the Rackett equation:

phi = (1-T/Tc)^(2/7) - (1-Tr/Tc)^(2/7)

```
double calculatePhi(double T, double Tr, double Tc){
  double l = T/Tc;
  double m = Tr/Tc;
  double n = 2/7.0;
  double q = (1-l);  //possibly negative
  double r = (1-m);  //possibly negative
  q = abs(q);
    double numa = Math.exp(n * Math.log(q));
  r = abs(r)
    double numb = Math.exp(n * Math.log(r));
  double phi = numa - numb;
  return phi;
}
```

See this link for mathematical proof:

[A Programmatic Approach to Finding a Real Solution to a Function Having a Potentially Negative Base and Fractional Exponent](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jp-OkRHoneFhH_Z8NxSDiQhVbvANDMCTH1rgTldsPvI/edit?usp=sharing)